# The url is not getting loaded completely, getting an error as "[SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer

Tags: selenium, zap

The url is not getting loaded completely, getting an error as "[SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.010" with below configurations:

Please pardon me since new to this.

Browser: Chrome 64
Selenium: 3.10.0
Build tool: maven (pom.xml)
Testng: 6.8

Scenario:
Use OWASP ZAP APIs with selenium functional test cases. below is the script:

```
 public void login() {
   // driver.get(BASE_URL);
    driver.navigate().to(BASE_URL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='btn btn-link']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

[image]

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    zapScanner = new ZAProxyScanner(ZAP_PROXYHOST,ZAP_PROXYPORT,ZAP_APIKEY);
    zapScanner.clear(); //Start a new session
    zapSpider = (Spider)zapScanner;
    log.info("Created client to ZAP API");
  driver = DriverFactory.createProxyDriver("chrome",createZapProxyConfigurationForWebDriver(), CHROME_DRIVER_PATH);
// driver = DriverFactory.createProxyDriver("firefox",createZapProxyConfigurationForWebDriver(), FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH);
    myApp = new MyAppNavigation(driver);
  //  myApp.registerUser(); //Doesn't matter if user already exists, bodgeit just throws an error
System.out.println("before test is done");
}


 @Test
public void testSecurityVulnerabilitiesAfterLogin() {
    System.out.println("started test");

    myApp.login();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 //   myApp.navigateAfterLogin();

    log.info("Spidering...");
    spiderWithZap();
    log.info("Spider done.");
}
```

Chrome browser is launched with the given base_url however it the url doesn't load completely and gives an error as shown in the attached screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Does Zap's complete loading? And is Zap's accessible from your computer? You can try accessing http://ZAP_PROXYHOST:ZAP_PROXYPORT/ui to check. If that page loaded, it means that everything is working on Zap's side, and it's time to check Zap's logs...

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. yes, able to access localhost:8090/ui successfully in Firefox/chrome browser when the browser LAN settings are same (localhost:8090). I am not able to see any related logs in zap.log file, i can see only the logs which were captured when ZAP GUI was running.This is the location where i am checking for logs: C:\Users\<Username>\OWASP ZAP_D>zap.log. Kindly guide me where can i see the logs.

Comment: If you can access the UI it is a good sign! You can check through the GUI or the API UI if Zap accessed any URL.  Zap might receive a timeout from your server. And [here](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQlogging) you can read more about logging, I would try to enable debug log and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, able to see zap logs now, the scan has been started, i can see few .js files recognized of our app however in between shows 'read time out' for the above issue (not loading the url completely) . I have added new screen shot with the log info. Please guide.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Also, `read time out` usually means that Zap got a timeout from upstream. If you can see the GUI, try re-sending the request and inspect it, it might cause your server to crash...